# Django static files giving 404 error after production in Microsoft Azure

Tags: django, azure, django-admin, django-staticfiles

My settings.py consist the following code:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'D:/home/site/wwwroot/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
    )
```

After pushing my code into github i deployed the github code in Azure and then i run "manage.py collectstatic --noinput" in Web Console of my Azure resource and when i run my project url the sttatic files still give 404 Error not found, even the admin css gives the same error though the static folder has admin css.

Can someone please help me figure out what might be my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that when DEBUG=False the static files URL of STATIC_ROOT was not defined so  had to explicitly define a URL in url.py which would point to static folder of STATIC_ROOT.

I solved it by changing the following code in settings.py as:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static-files')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'D:/home/site/wwwroot/static',
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
```

and then i added the following to my urls.py as:

```
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}), 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but fortunately I was able to solve it based on the above answer. However, it needs to be slightly changed.
Working solution for django==3.0.8

settings.py make sure to have it like:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'D:/home/site/wwwroot/static',
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
```

urls.py need to be like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
 re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT})
]
```